# Google HTTP load balancing enforce HTTPS

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have a HTTP and HTTPS load balancer on Goole Cloud. Is it possible to set it up to enforce (redirect) all connections to HTTPS?

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/733166/redirect-all-http-traffic-to-https-when-using-the-https-load-balancer-on-googl. check for `X-Forwarded-Proto = 'http'` header on your backend service and do  a 301 redirection to https.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not at the load balancer as of June 2015.

As an alternative, you can configure your web servers to return 301 for all HTTP requests redirecting to the HTTPS version.

For Apache (from https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.example.com
   Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
   ServerName www.example.com
   DocumentRoot /my/document/root
   SSLEngine On
   # .. etc .
</VirtualHost>
```

For nginx (from https://serverfault.com/questions/67316/in-nginx-how-can-i-rewrite-all-http-requests-to-https-while-maintaining-sub-dom):

```
server {
    listen [::]:80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I already do but I really wanted the lb to do it for me. I hope Google adds this functionality.

Comment: Did you experience any issues with the default health checks on your HTTP load balancer. I've a similar configuration setup with nginx, and the health check is failing and therefore I'm getting a 502 Server error when trying to access the my site via the load balancer. If I hit a vm directly it correctly redirects to http so I'm aboutt 99% positive it's not an nginx config issue.

Comment: I have settings just like that but experiencing a different problem. When I access the http://... I see:
_Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please._

Looks like google load balancer "catches" the 301 and redirects the http request to my https endpoint. Has anyone solution for this?

Comment: Does this require that the Load Balancer have 2 backends, an HTTP and an HTTPS backend? my current configuration only has HTTPS backend and my app itself thinks all requests are already HTTPS even if the url in the browser is HTTP

Answer (score -3):

Why bother to redirect? You could easily create new (SSL) global forwarding rule and point it to your backend service.

For example, http://107.178.251.37/ points to my HTTP backend and I've added another global forwarding rule to make it SSL: https://107.178.240.233/.

Comment: Because I don't want to allow plain http connections. The set up you have described is already what I have, but I want clients to be redirected to https. I can do it from my server but i was hoping the lb could handle it for me.